# cython best practices : importing enums and structs from C++ sources?

Tags: c++, import, enums, struct, cython

What would be the nicest way to expose enum and struct from extern C++ ?

Right now I just did this :

```
# Redefine 't_output' enum type (no other way to do ??)
cdef public enum t_deptype:
    IND_DEP  = 1
    SITE_DEP = 2
    ENV_DEP  = 4
```

But redefining is kind of unsatisfying to my eyes.
Every web page I've been through deals with the same kind of rewriting...

And do I have to do the same with structs ?

Thanks

Comment: Pick a tool such as Clang that parses C++ source code and generates output that is much easier to parse. From there you can extract the information you need and generate the final enum export.

Comment: Well, sorry, my question was a bit partial. I try to make myself more clear : I have an external huge C++ library, that I compiled into a shared object. I load it from cython to expose its features, that's why rewriting instead of simply exposing it isn't satisfying : I was expecting a nice way to access enums and struct  without to change anything in my foreign library (which I like implemented this way). The cython bridge to python must stay a bridge... What is the common way (even with more code than the one I pasted above). The recommanded one ?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what Clang would be for me, please. Thanks a lot